# Filter Enums based on List in LINQ

Tags: linq, enums

I Have a Enum

```
public enum ProcessStatus: byte
{
    NotStarted = 0,
    PreCheckStarted= 1,
    PreCheckCompleted= 2,
    Processing= 3,
    Failed= 4,
    Completed= 5,
    Closed= 6
}
```

in Table we have entries like 0,3,5,6

we need list of Enums based on some criteria and criteria is List which contains 0,1,2

i am able to get all Enums as List Like

```
 Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProcessStatus)).OfType<ProcessStatus>()
```

and have

```
List<byte> processListIDs
```

which contains IDs

i want

```
 IEnumerable<ProcessStatus> filtered based on ids in processListIDs using LINQ.
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the connection between a process list ID and the ProcessStatus enum?

Comment: processListIDs contains list of different ProcessStatus,  say we want to perform some action on Process having status NotStarted and Failed, so processListIDs  contains 0,4. now i want list of ProcessStatus enum which should contain something like {(0,NotStarted),(4,Failed)} so that i can populated this in dropDown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Intersect` with better performance:

```
  var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof (ProcessStatus))
                     .OfType<ProcessStatus>().Cast<byte>();

  var result = enumList.Intersect(processListIDs)
                       .Cast<ProcessStatus>();
```

Comment: what if processListIDs of IEnumerable<byte?>

Answer (score 1):

```
var res =
    processStatusCollection.Where(item => processListIDs.Contains((int)item));
```

Comment: what is processStatusCollection?

Comment: A collection of all possible enum types

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Enum.TryParse<TEnum>`:

```
List<byte> processListIDs = new List<byte>() { 0, 3, 5, 6 };
ProcessStatus ps = ProcessStatus.NotStarted;
IEnumerable<ProcessStatus> status = processListIDs
    .Where(p => Enum.TryParse<ProcessStatus>(p.ToString(), out ps))
    .Select(p => ps);
```

Comment: @Kaushal: Because [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) needs it as out-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var p = new List<byte>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 };
IEnumerable<ProcessStatus> result = p.Select(o => (ProcessStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProcessStatus), o.ToString()));

/// do something with result
```